# Is the interior of the tensor product of two convex cones equal to the tensor product of their interiors?

Tags: general-topology, convex-geometry

Let $C \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ and $D \subseteq \mathbb{R}^m$ be convex cones in Euclidean $n$- and $m$-space respectively, both containing their respective origins.

Let $M \in C \otimes D$ be given, i.e. $M = c_1 \otimes_{\mathbb{R}} d_1 + \cdots + c_N \otimes_{\mathbb{R}} d_N \in \mathbb{R}^n \otimes_{\mathbb{R}} \mathbb{R}^m$ for some $c_1, \dots,c_N \in C$ and $d_1, \dots, d_N \in D$.

If $M$ lies in the interior of $C \otimes D \subseteq  \mathbb{R}^n \otimes_{\mathbb{R}} \mathbb{R}^m$, does there exists $p_1, \dots, p_M$ in the interior of $C$ and $q_1, \dots, q_M$ in the interior of $D$ such that
$$M = p_1 \otimes_{\mathbb{R}} q_1 + \cdots + p_M \otimes_{\mathbb{R}} q_M?$$

Denoting the interior of a cone $C$ by $C^\circ$, the question is essentially asking whether
$$(C \otimes D)^\circ = C^\circ \otimes D^\circ.$$

Comment: I think as stated, the question actually translates to $(C\otimes D)^\circ \subseteq C^\circ\otimes D^\circ$. which one do you want ? Also what have you tried ? Is there some context to this question (where you found it) ?

Comment: dear Quinton, yes, you are right that the question just asks for this inclusion.

Comment: also asked at https://mathoverflow.net/q/444687/11260